# Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'. on React Native with Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, native

Iam new to React Native and iam trying to set up an environment for when I am running the command "npm start android" This is the error I am facing

```
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package
```

I have tried all the available solutions on the internet, but none seems to be wiping data from the emulator device, restarting the emulator, and clearing the cache. Any help would be really appreciated.
Many thanks for considering my request.